# "Over the coming months, the giraffes range far and wide." - Why is the sentence not in a future tense, despite having "over the coming months"?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, future-constructions

**"Over the coming months, the giraffes range far and wide."** [BBC - Giraffes released into new home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMArIVFeUQA) (see:3:18-3:23)

As we know, **"Over the coming months ...."** clearly refers to future, so you would expect it to be followed by something like **"Over the coming months, the giraffes are going to range ..."** however, the speaker is using a simple present tense after it.

Why might that be?

Comment: We often use Simple Present to refer to future actions - *He starts a new job on Monday, I leave for London tomorrow,...* In your cited context, it's quite natural to use Simple Present to add "immediacy".

Comment: It's not in the future, anyway – the narrative was presumably written after the filming was completed. An alternative phrasing might be "Over the next few months the  giraffes ranged far and wide."

Comment: @WeatherVane: True, but "future in the past" *Over the next few months the giraffes **would range** far and wide* is also perfectly natural in the cited context (a nature documentary), where as with my previous comment, such choices of verb form emphasize "immediacy" by blurring the distinction between "now" (time of speaking) and the (past) time-frame being referenced.

Comment: [tag:historical-present] cannot be used as tag for this question, as that would make it seem the OP knows about historical present. (If the OP knew about the historical present, this question would have not been asked.)

Comment: @Lambie I did not vote neither the question nor the answers. I am not sure why you thought that somebody who posted a comment about which tags are more appropriate should also down-vote your answer.

Comment: @Lambie Well, I would not add [tag:articles] to a question asking what *the*, *an*, and *a* are. It would seem the OP knows about articles but does not know that those are articles. Similar effect would have adding that tag to this question, or adding a tag that is essentially the answer to the question.

Comment: It's not a matter of not knowing the existing tags. It's just that it would be "hilarious" to see [tag:historical-present] in a question where the OP shows not to know what historical present is.

Comment: @Lambie You had a moderator who said it's fine and a moderator who said it's not fine when the tag name is the answer itself.

Comment: @Lambie Tags are for the question, not the answer. To make an example, if an answer for a question that asks for an word suggests an adjective, [tag:adjectives] is not added to the question, because the question is not expressly asking about adjectives. Similarly, this question does not ask what *historic present* is, but why the sentence is using the Simple Present after when it starts with *Over the coming months*. The "funny" effect is that, with that tag, it would seem the OP knows about historic present, but asks why the Simple Present is used in that tense.

Comment: As a side note, there is no need to say *a one star mod said*, considering you were actually posting a comment for a *one star mod*. It would also help to get a link to that chat, since the recent chat messages are not about tags that can be added to questions.

Comment: @Lambie Does the question explicitly ask *What is historic present?* No, it does not. It asks why the Simple Present tense is used in that sentence. It is the answer that says that is an example of historic present usage.

Comment: @Lambie Trolling? Wait, you said *a star mod told me in the ELL chat*, but there are not chat messages about that.

Comment: @Lambie Yet, the question does not explicitly ask *What is "historic present"?* Asking, for example, if a sentence is using historic present, or if historic present can be used in a specific context, is different from asking *Why is the Simple Present tense used in this sentence?* In the later case, the answer is *It's an example of historic present.* but in the first two cases, the answer is surely not *It's an example of historic present.*

Comment: Furthermore: Yes, our job is to inform them of what they do not know. That is not in any way related to the tags to use for a question; it is related to what goes in an answer.

Comment: @Lambie Or you do not understand how to correctly use tags. I do not even know why you started with these comments, when it was not you who added the tag I removed.

Comment: @Lambie: "@apaderno Yes, if the OP had known, s/he would not have asked the question. I would really like to put an exclamation mark there but am told it's considered rude. Tags can be edited post facto, why not? In any case, I received two downvotes on my answer. My goodness. And even if you don't like that, my answer certainly does not deserve a downvote." It was you who posted a comment for me, not me who posted a comment for you.

Comment: I didn't post "@Lambie historical-present cannot be used as tag for this question, as that would make it seem the OP knows about historical present. (If the OP knew about the historical present, this question would have not been asked.)"

Comment: @Lambie Was that addressed to you? No. Therefore, I didn't start to post comments addressed to you. You started to post comments addressed to me, probably to complain because you thought I down-voted your answer. I only replied to your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were watching excerpts of a football match on the sports news, the news announcer, referring to an *upcoming* play, might say something like:

> Watch how the center forward *passes* the ball between two defenders in this next play.

The events, in real life, have already happened, and the film excerpt has its own temporal context.  There is no prediction involved, no intention, no  "expression of futurity", merely an expression of *what is known to occur*.

Compare also a context like this:

> What time does the train for London leave the station tomorrow?
>
> -- Tomorrow, the train *departs* at 8:15AM.

What is being expressed is *what is now expected to occur*.

Present knowledge. Present expectation.

Comment: "referring to an upcoming play, might say something like:" No, that would be use of the present to refer to **a play that was already made**: Watch how the center forward passes the ball//not upcoming, past.

Comment: @Lambie: I am beginning to wonder about your reading comprehension skills. Read again.

Comment: That use of the simple present is not the use of the simple present in the OP's question. That use by the BBC is present of narration aka historical present and is clearly a past situation.

Comment: @Lambie  You simply do not read carefully enough for me to engage in any sort of meaningful dialogue with you.

Comment: How can an **upcoming play** (a future occurence, even if soon) use the word 'passes", which *you then qualify as having occured*? That seems contradictory. Instead of making personal comments, try to understand what I am saying that makes those comments seem odd. I am a very careful reader and listener.

Comment: @Lambie: But it isn't a future occurence. It's the sports *news* playing excerpts of games that have already been played.  The play  referenced by the news announcer is  "upcoming"  within the temporal context of the news but is something from the  (recent) past.  It's a situation analogous to a documentary whose footage is of something that has already happened.

Comment: "temporal context of the news"  and "upcoming" are very confusing. They are just reporting on something that in a recent past. I think you mean "upcoming play" in the sense of people watching something that has been filmed already but it was very confusing because you didn't say anything about it already having been filmed.

Comment: @Lambie: I said it was the sports news (not a live broadcast of the game) and I said "The events, in real life, have already happened". The news announcer uses the words "upcoming play" because he already knows what happens in the film, just as the voice-over in the documentary knows what those elephants do "over the *coming* months".  The direct parallels between the post-game news broadcast and the wildlife documentary are abundantly clear.

Answer (score 0):

> What is Historic Present?
> **Historic present (also known as dramatic present or narrative present) is the usage of the present tense to describe things of the
> past.**
>
> It is a stylistic device that is used in literature to make the story
> more vivid, immediate and exciting. It is often used to draw the
> reader into the experience of the story itself, making it more
> dramatic. The idea is to remove the story from its original time
> period to bring it to the present. In a way, this brings the story
> much closer to the reader.

[narrative present](https://www.papertrue.com/blog/present-tense-narratives-in-novels/)

It's a literary device but is also used in descriptive writing in journalistic pieces.